# How to use alternate image url when image url is empty in android?

Tags: android, json, image, image-processing, alternate

Here i am displaying a image where image url is fetched by parsing JSON.
It works fine up to now.
Here is the code :

```
ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listicon);
//TAG_IMAGE is tag name of image url which i got from parsing JSON
String imageUrl = (String) data.get(TAG_IMAGE);
        try {

                Drawable image = ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(),
                        imageUrl);
                iconImageView.setImageDrawable(image);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I wan to display the alternative image url if imageUrl is empty.
How can i do this ??
I had tried the following code but it doesnot display the alternate image i.e testUrl in below code. Even it doesnot print `System.out.println("image empty and showing alternate image");` in logcat too.

**Solved on its own:** 
The correct code works for me is:

```
String imageUrl = (String) data.get(TAG_IMAGE);


if (imageUrl.equals("") ) {

            System.out.println("image empty");
            String rUrl = "http://www.windypress.com/mediakit/moon/icon/moon-icon-full-72.png";
            try {

                Drawable image2 = ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(),
                        rUrl);
                iconImageView.setImageDrawable(image2);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("has image");
            try {

                Drawable image1 = ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(),
                        imageUrl);
                iconImageView.setImageDrawable(image1);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print your `imageUrl` before checking. `imageUrl` is not null. It may be empty but not null. Check for `imageUrl.length() > 0`